# Creating primary keys in zero or one to one relationship in lightswitch

Tags: entity-framework, entity-relationship, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have two table, the first one has a primary key but it is not auto increment, the another one has a primary key and also auto increment. I need set value of the second primary key to the first one.

```
TABLE1 primary key         TABLE2 primary key
zero or one   ------------ one
```

I have this relationship when I inserted a new record to TABLE1, TABLE2 primary key was not inserting to TABLE1 primary key. Value is 0. How can I resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This depends on the association mapping. Can you show the details? BTW composite key is a key consisting of more than one column in the same table :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to be set automatically, you'll have to add a record to *Table2*, & set the reference to it yourself, in *Table1*'s *Inserting* method.

Just because you have the relationship defined between them doesn't mean that the *Table2* record will automatically be added, nor the *Table1* FK either.

Or have I misunderstood what you were asking?

EDIT:

```
partial void PERSONELs_Inserting(PERSONEL entity) 
{ 
    entity.refPersonelID = entity.Personelyetki.Id; 
}
```

If *refPersonelID* is just an **integer** property, then the code above should work fine. If it's not just a plain integer property then I still don't understand what the problem is. What error are you getting?

I'll give you an example of how to set a navigation property, using *Table1* & *Table2*. I'm assuming a 1-Many relationship between them, so *Table1* has a navigation collection property called *Table2s*, & *Table2* has a navigation property called *Table1*. I don't fully understand what you're actually trying to do, but the example code below illustrates the **correct** way to set a navigation property.

To set Table2's Table1 property, you would do this:

```
private void UpdateTable1
{
    //retrieve the Table1 entity that corresponds to the required integer ID value (someIdValue)
    var table = this.Details.DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.Table1Set.SingleOrDefault(someIdValue);

    //assign the retrieved entity to the navigation property
    this.Table1 = table;

    //you CAN'T do this
    this.Tbale1.ID = someIdValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I can't set primary key it is read only and the tables are in different Odatas. Do you have any example code?

Comment: I didn't say set the KEY value, I know they're read-only (that's from Entity Framework, which is used by LightSwitch), I said set the REFERENCE to it. You didn't give the names of your navigation properties so I wasn't able to be more specific. If you're coding INSIDE LightSwitch, OData makes no difference. If you show me the code (the full method, not just a piece of it, it needs to be in context), maybe I can point out where you're going wrong.

Comment: _"It's not going to be set automatically, you'll have to add a record to Table2, & set the reference to it yourself, in Table1's Inserting method."_ I set the reference but it doesnt work. How can I do? thanks for help

Comment: `partial void PERSONELs_Inserting(PERSONEL entity)
 {
  entity.refPersonelID = entity.Personelyetki.Id;
 }`                                                                entity is PERSONEL table,Personelyetki is Personeller Table. refPersonelID is PERSONEL reference key.

Comment: It's not possible to set an entity's ID property directly like that. You need to retrieve a Personelyetki entity using the id value that you have available, then set entity.Personelyetki to the retrieved entity. I'll add an example in my original answer.